# Reversing a path in Raphael.js

Tags: svg, raphael

I have two curved paths, both roughly going from left to right, one above the .  I need to join them up with straight lines into a closed path.

To do this, I am assuming I need to build the path string of the big closed path.  But in order to build the path, I need to reverse the second curve.

How can I reverse a path in Raphael.js?  Or is there a better way to do what I want to do?

Thanks.

Comment: The approach I'm considering at the moment is looping through the segments of the path and trying to build the reverse of the path from this.  I'm thinking this is going to be a bit of a convoluted way to do it - can anyone save me from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using this example?

It creates 2 independent paths running left to right. Then it merges these into a closed path.

Try in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sudipto/CTNWb/).

EDITED:

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 800, 600);

// Define 2 paths running left to right
var path1 = paper.path("M10 10L200 120 300 80 400 100 450 150")
                 .attr({stroke: "#00FF00"}),
    path2 = paper.path("M10 200L200 220 300 280 400 300 450 250")
                .attr({stroke: "#00FF00"}),

    closedPath = joinPaths(path1, path2)
                      .attr({ 
                            fill: "#FF0000", 
                            stroke: "#0000FF"
                        });


// This function is a poc and assumes that 
// the paths contain a "M" at the begining
// and that that "M" is replacable by "L" (absolute Line to) 

function joinPaths() {
    var i, 
        len = arguments.length, 
        pathArr =[], 
        finalPathArr =[];

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        pathArr[i] = arguments[i].attr("path");
        if (i) {
            pathArr[i][0][0] = "L";
            pathArr[i].reverse();
            if (i === len-1) {
                pathArr[i].push("Z");
            }
        }
        finalPathArr = finalPathArr.concat(pathArr[i]);      
    }

    return paper.path(finalPathArr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's close: check my result here: http://jsfiddle.net/CTNWb/11/.  The two paths are joined properly on one side, but there's an unwanted curve on the other side.  Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly due to the use of 'C'. My paths were created using 'L'. In this case, we need to decide whether we will join the terminal points using a curved line or a straight line and then modify the function.

Comment: I see - I would like to join the terminal points using a straight line - can you give me any pointers on how to make the function do that?

Comment: Marking this as accepted as it got me 90% of the way there - ended up just creating two more paths from the start and end points of my curves, and joining all 4 paths using this function.

Comment: Thanks. Since C uses 3 pairs of coordinates, it needs some level of management while traversing backward. I will try posting some code once I get some time for it. :D

Answer (score 0):

I needed this functionality recently to fill the area between to curves on a graph. I used the following implementation.

```js
function reversePath(pathString) {
    var pathPieces = pathString.match(/[MLHVCSQTA][-0-9.,]*/gi);
    var reversed = '';
    var skip = true;
    var previousPathType;
    for (var i = pathPieces.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var pathType = pathPieces[i].substr(0, 1);
        var pathValues = pathPieces[i].substr(1);
        switch (pathType) {
            case 'M':
            case 'L':
                reversed += (skip ? '' : pathType) + pathValues;
                skip = false;
                break;
            case 'C':
                var curvePieces = pathValues.match(/^([-0-9.]*,[-0-9.]*),([-0-9.]*,[-0-9.]*),([-0-9.]*,[-0-9.]*)$/);
                reversed += curvePieces[3] + pathType + curvePieces[2] + ',' + curvePieces[1] + ',';
                skip = true;
                break;
            default:
                alert('Not implemented: ' + pathType);
                break;
        }
    }
    return reversed;
}
```

And I would call it like so:

```
var combinedPath = path1 + 'L' + reversePath(path2) + 'Z';
```

Comment: How would you go about a path containing Q (quadratic curves) ?

Comment: @rassoh I do not know how I would handle that. All of my curves were very simple. I would start by reading up on the syntax for quadratic curves and see if it is possible to formulate the values in reverse.